# How can i make 2 id attributes work on the same HTML element?

Tags: html

I have a `<input>`-element that needs 2 different id attributes. Is there a way to make it have 2 id attributes in one `<input>`? One id is for the CSS while the other id is for JavaScript.
How can i make this work? Here's an example of the code I'm trying to find a way to make it work.

```
<input type="button" id="button1" id="reset" value="Subscribe">
```

`id="button1"` is for the CSS, while `id="reset"` I need for JavaScript since a click of that button will make a number above the button go up. But I need a way to clarify to it that `id="reset"` is for the JavaScript, which is on the same page as the HTML is, and the CSS is on the same page as well, obviously using the style tags.

Comment: No, an element can only have a single `id`.  Use a `class` for the CSS instead.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer: feel free to clarify why you think you need another attribute than `id="button1"` to target your element with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use more than one `id`-attribute on the same DOM element (its no valid HTML otherwise)! You should use another attribute for your JavaScript approach. For Example:

```
<input type="button" id="button1" class="jsReset" value="Subscribe">
```

or

```
<input type="button" id="button1" data-js-id="reset" value="Subscribe">
```

or whatever seems suitable to you.

**An id in general is meant to be unique!** So you should use `id="button1"` also only on one element at the same time as well.

---

## [Reference (w3.org)](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-id)

> This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.

## [Reference (validator.w3.org)](https://validator.w3.org/nu/)

validating against `<input type="button" id="button1" id="reset" value="Subscribe">` throws:

> Error: Duplicate attribute id.

---

BTW: Maybe you should clarify why...

> while id="reset" i need for javascript since a click of that button will make a number above the button go up

...you need another attribute than `id="button1"` to target your element with JavaScript. You can use

```
document.getElementById('button1')
jQuery('#button1') // if you already use jQuery
```

So I can not see why you have to add another attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Specifies a style ID - a unique name for the element that is used to change its style and access to it through scripts. The identifier in the document code must be in a single instance, in other words, only occur once.